# Slow lazy load of Accessibility.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my WPF application, the first time the user opens a menu there is a pause caused by the lazy loading of Accessibility.dll.

As you can imagine this is very annoying so I would like to force load this assembly at startup.  I have tried several ways of doing this with no luck. e.g using Assembly.Load() or AppDomain.Load().  None of these calls result in the assembly loading (i.e. I get no AssemblyLoaded event.  I have tried directly referencing the assmebly in order to get the correct AssemblyName for calling these methods but still no luck.

What is the correct way to make this happen?

Many Thanks
Dan

Edit: Call stack on assembly load (after clicking a menu)

mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyLoadEvent(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssemblyLoadedAssemly
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(bool asyncCall)

The call from Popup is:

_secHelper.ForceMsaaToUiaBridge(_popupRoot.Value);

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use reflection ([`RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.preparemethod.aspx)) to force JIT compiler to compile methods you want, in a background thread. Here is a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31316/Pre-compile-pre-JIT-your-assembly-on-the-fly-or-tr) which describes that.

`RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` is thread safe, so it's safe to use in this scenario.

This is the code, slightly modified to exclude generic and P/Invoked functions:

```
Thread jitter = new Thread(() =>
{
   var flags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
               BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | 
               BindingFlags.Static;

   foreach (var assembly in AssembliesToPreload)
       foreach (var type in a.GetTypes())
           foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(flags))
           {
                if (method.ContainsGenericParameters || 
                    method.IsGenericMethod || 
                    method.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
                    continue;

                if ((method.Attributes & MethodAttributes.PinvokeImpl) > 0)
                    continue;

                RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle);
           }
   }
});

jitter.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
jitter.Start();
```

Comment: It seems that Accessibility.dll just contains a few interfaces so not sure if I can apply this technique.  I have added the call stack above when the assembly is first loaded on opening a menu.

Comment: @HansPassant: you're right, I didn't realize it was a framework assembly. Although I haven't used it so far, if I got it right, it's a COM wrapper, so the bottleneck might be the instantiation of the COM object? If it's supposed to be used in a STA model, OP will still have to instantiate it in a GUI thread, so background init won't help.

Comment: Still an init on the UI thread at startup would be better than waiting for a menu to be opened.. perhaps I should just kludge by opening and closing a hidden menu once the app is loaded!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a type in your Accessibility.dll that you want to instance or use.

I think that whats taking time here is the JIT, so to force the JIT to run just create/use an instance of your object. I tend to add methods like Accessibility.RunJIT() when I'm in a similar situation. What I do then is just to create an instance of the class.

You could also look at NGen. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry I was unclear in my question, I was refering to the framework assembly Accessibility.dll.